# Как сделать мультиязычность в боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Пишу телеграм-бота...

Хочу в него добавить возможность выбирать язык. Он на айограме.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Можно добавить возможность пользователю выбрать язык. А потом, в зависимости от выбранного языка, выдавать необходимое сообщение.

Comment: вопрос был изменён

Comment: я рассматривал этот вариант он в принципе нормальный но я бы хотел попробовать другой способ

Comment: Ответы на такой вопрос есть в интернете. Он вам поможет куда больше, чем сообщество ;) Ваш вопрос без конкретики: не понятна структура проекта, как вы прикрепляете тексты при отправке сообщений. Уточните детали, пожалуйста.